# Is it possible to run C source code from Java?

Tags: java, c

Now I have some C source codes, I would like to use it in my java application. 
I need to execute the C source code, and get back the result to my java application. Instead of re-write all the C source code to java, how can I reuse the C's source code in my java application?

Comment: It's not possible to run C source code at all unless you can find a C interpreter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that
>   enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and
>   to be called by native applications (programs specific to a
>   hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other
>   languages such as C, C++ and assembly.

Answer (score 9):

There are the following ways.

1. JNI (see answer of @AurelioDeRosa +1)
2. JNA
3. If your C program can run as command line utility why not just to execute it using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() or ProcessBuilder?

Answer (score 6):

Two options:

1. Make a library accessible via JNI or JNA
2. Make an executable, and call it with ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec and capture the output streem if needed

Comment: +1 - The second method is sometimes good too (I've used it in the past).

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible Take a look at

[Calling C Code from Java](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.09/CallingCCodefromJava/index.html)